# In Libreoffice calc, how can I compute until something happens?

Tags: libreoffice

In Libreoffice calc, can I compute columns until something happens? Like compute 2 raised to the power i while the result is less than 10 raised to the power 2023 and store the values to the cells A1, A2, ..., An.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in LibreOffice Calc by using a formula and the `IF` function. Here is an example formula that you can use in cell `A1` and then copy down to the cells below:

```
=IF(2^A1<10^2023,2^A1,"")
```

This formula checks if 2 raised to the power of the current cell value is less than 10 raised to the power 2023. If it is, it returns the result, otherwise, it returns an empty string. The `IF` function allows you to stop the calculation when the condition is no longer met.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with arbitrary precision integers.

Comment: You still calculate the result though, only to discard it

Comment: And you can't put this formula into cell A1 - you'll get a loop error